# How does 'Source Stamping' work?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, pdb-files

In a presentation by Bungie (A Life on a Bungie Farm) a feature in Visual Studio named 'Source Stamping' is mentioned. I would like to read a bit more information on that subject but finding related information on MSDN proofed to be difficult.

> "We also use a feature of Visual Studio called source stamping, which is a linker setting that is used to specify the final location on a server of the version of the source code that was used to build a certain set of binaries.  The source is copied up to that location when the build finishes, and since that location is stamped into the pdbs Visual Studio knows that when it is debugging a build off the build site, it should pull the source from that location to use while stepping through the code.
>   "

What I am looking for is some information that describes the linker setting(s) in question to setup a similar build/debug-environment.

To complement my question. I may have been a bit premature. A part in the presentation that I over-read mentions the exact linker setting /SOURCEMAP. But this appears to be undocumented.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680641%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Answer (score 2):

This feature is called [Source Server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680641(v=vs.85).aspx), where the information needed to extract the right source revision is embedded into the PDB using the tools and scripts listed on the Source Server page.

Using this system, as long as you have access to the private (unstripped) PDBs for your project, your debugger can retrieve the original source file from your version control system. Supported systems are Team Foundation Server, Perforce, Visual SourceSafe, CVS, and Subversion.

Comment: While Source Server looks as great solution giving a similar end-goal, its functionality described on MSDN doesn't match with the description in the presentation.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the specific details, but the compiler can very probably put some cryptographic quality hash of the source code in the executable.

(Imagine that you'll add in the executable the md5sum -or better- of a source code compiled in).